# Copy filename to file with same number

Tags: filenames

So this is a bit vague to describe so I'll use a picture:

[image]

I have around 150 DWG files that have the same content as the SVG's (they're both vector drawing formats converted 1 to 1). I'd like to apply the same filename from the DWG's to the SVG's that start with the same number.

So I end up with:

```
001_TERMINAL.dwg
001_TERMINAL.svg
002_DIFFUSER.dwg
002_DIFFUSER.svg
```

etcetera...

I'm using a PC with Windows 10.

How can I implement a solution to my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to end up with `001.dwg`, `001.svg`; `002.dwg`, `002.svg`, etc.?

Comment: No, I want to copy the dwg names. So 001_longname.dwg, 001_longname.svg etc.

Comment: what do you mean by "same content" ? dwg and svg are different  formats. Plus, please provide example of situation before and after renaming, as it is not clear.

Comment: OK will do some changes to make it more clear including an example

Comment: This is incredibly vague and totally off topic for this site. What technology should the solution be implemented in? what environment are you running on? what have you tried to solve yourself? what are you stuck on? I would vote to close this immediately if it didn't have a bounty

Comment: Not off topic at all IMO. There is even a special tag for this with similar questions.. I'm on a Windows PC, I'll update the OP with that info. I've tried searching for answers of course but this a kind of unique situation. What I'm stuck on is pretty clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are on Windows, PowerShell is a great candidate to solve this.

For the script below, the length of the numeric part in front of the underscore character doesn't matter, as long as there is an underscore in the .dwg filename, as visible in your question.

Just replace 'c:\folder' here below with the path your files are stored in.

```
$folderPath = "c:\folder" 

$files = Get-ChildItem ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($folderPath, "?*_*.dwg"))

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) 
{
    $file = $files[$i]    
    $dwgFileName = $file.BaseName
    $index = $dwgFileName.IndexOf("_")    
    $numberPart = $dwgFileName.Substring(0, $index)
    $svgFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($folderPath, "$numberPart.svg")

    if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($svgFilePath))
    {
        Rename-Item -Path $svgFilePath -NewName "$dwgFileName.svg"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's always 3 digits in the *.svg file names:

```
set DIR=C:\mydir

@rem Allow repeated setting of !variables! in the FOR loop below
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%I in (%DIR%\*.dwg) do (
  @rem "~n" to pick out just the filename part of the %%I variable
  set BASENAME=%%~nI

  @rem Substring - batch file style
  set PREFIX=!BASENAME:~0,3!

  echo !PREFIX! ... !BASENAME!
  rename !PREFIX!.svg !BASENAME!.svg
)
```

Note this will need to be in a batch file for the `%%I` to work.

The main complication there is using variables in a multi-line FOR loop.

For these you have to use the delayed expansion option, to enable the variable to be expanded each time round, rather than when the line is parsed.  This means you have to use `!variable!` instead of the more normal `%variable%` in a batch file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I select a folder in this situation?

Comment: Directory name added to the example - it's at the top of the batch file in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.dwg; do
    IFS='_' read -r -a arr <<< "$f"
    mv ${arr[0]}.svg ${f%.*}.svg
done
```

Comment: it's unclear what does what in your reply. Also what is bash, and how do I select a folder to run it on?

Comment: This is a bash script (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) and is intended to be run in the folder in which you want to rename the files. You can run  in Unix environment but you didn't specify any environment.

Comment: I only have access to a Windows PC unfortunately. I'll update the OP